# Lightning page not showing on mobile

Tags: lightning, mobile

we have report charts as part of our "Phone" lightining page. However I am not seeing these charts (nor other parts of the phone lightnig page, for that matter) on my Mobile device. I did verify that I assigned the page for the correct app and for "Desktop and Phone". What am I missing?[image: light]

Comment: can you add the page assignment detail of this lightning page as screenshot?

Comment: Thanks, Sanket. We got it working by creating a VF page with the report charts